# How to access Windows.Management.Deployment namespace in a Desktop project in VS2017?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

**Question**: Where in Windows 10 we can find `Windows.Management.Deployment.dll` or how can we install it?

In a `WinForm` project in `VS2017 - ver 15.9.6` I'm trying to follow `C#` example of [PackageManager.FindUsers(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findusers#Windows_Management_Deployment_PackageManager_FindUsers_System_String_) method that uses classes from `Windows.Management.Deployment` namespace.

But can't seem to find the location of above dll that is needed to add a reference in `VS2017` project. I installed [UwpDestop](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UwpDesktop) NuGet package, also add a reference to `windows.winmd` file, but that did not help either. I'm using `Windows 10 Pro- Update 1809`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the Windows.Management.Deployment namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016645/how-to-access-the-windows-management-deployment-namespace)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Winforms project you need to go to "Add Reference …" and hit the "Browse" button. Then navigate here and select the Windows.winmd file that corresponds to the Windows SDK you are targeting. Be sure to change the file extension filter to *.*

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I've already added `Windows.winmd`. I've Windows 10 - `update 1809` that probably means I'm targeting  SDK [10.0.17763](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). So, I chose `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17763.0` folder for `Windows.winmd`. `10.0.17763.0` is the latest version folder inside `UnionMetadata`

Comment: Adding the Windows.winmd is all you need. Don't use the Nuget package, it is outdated. Make sure you use a current version of the .NET Framework. Here is my test project - can you share yours that shows it doesn't work?
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AovTwKUMywTNsOk9z5EKp_Qth5wF8A

Comment: In your test project you are using `Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager`, whereas; in the `C#` example of the link I provided in my post above, they are using `using Windows.Deployment.PackageManager;`. I tried your suggestion `Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager` and it works fine. (thank you). Is the MS online C# example using wrong `using` statement, maybe a typo on their example? Because their `using` statement still does not work even in your test project. Regardless, later I'm going to mark your response as an answer since it resolved my issue;

Comment: This is a doc bug. Windows.Deployment.PackageManager is an old thing (from Windows Phone 8, if I remember correctly). Please use Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager.

Comment: Note, this process is now deprecated in .NET 5 onwards. Microsoft has made breaking changes where they explain here https://aka.ms/netsdk1130

Comment: Just downloaded and installed newest SDK version (22000.194.210911-1543) and guess what's missing: "Windows.winmd".

Answer (score 0):

search path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0` in `regedit editor`, and install the missing version.

[image: example]

or modify the `HeloLens.Automation.csproj`

```
<!-- Fall back to old, unversioned location -->
<HintPath Condition="'$([System.IO.File]::Exists(%(HintPath)))'=='false'">$(Windows10SdkPath)\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
```

to

```
<!-- Fall back to old, unversioned location -->
<HintPath Condition="'$([System.IO.File]::Exists(%(HintPath)))'=='false'">$(Windows10SdkPath)\UnionMetadata\<the version installed in your machine>\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
```