# Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager - returning ComObject in desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, .net-core, msix

I have a NetCore3.1 WPF Application (Windows 10, VS2019). I can pack it as MSIX app (using [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)).
In the `.appxmanifest` file I added:

```xml
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  <rescap:Capability Name="packageQuery" />
</Capabilities>
```

I can install and use my application without problems. The problem is that I try to use the [Windows.Management API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54455263) in my application like so:

```cs
var pkgManager = new Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager();
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = pkgManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
```

I dont get any exceptions when using this but the `packages` variable value is `System.__ComObject`.

I dont understand what exactly is that and why am I not getting the desired result - a list of all installed msix packages for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to (sort of) solve my problem.

I still have no idea why is my *packages* variable *System.__ObjectCom* and what exactly is *System.__ObjectCom* but it seems that if one treats this object as the supposed-to-be object (in my case *IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>*) its ok.

So basically, the following produced something (much to my surprise):

```
    IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = pkgManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
    List<string> installedAppsDisplayNAme = new List<string>();
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        installedAppsDisplayNAme.Add(package.DisplayName);
    }
```

Comment: `System.__ObjectCom` is presumably .NET Core's representation of a [COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal). One feature of COM objects is that they support runtime reflection. If you are requesting an interface (like `IEnumerable`) the object in question knows whether it implements that interface. If it doesn't, it returns an error code that surfaces as an exception in C#. If it does everything goes as expected. Either way the operation is safe.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.